# Error in opening a dropdown using Python and Kv in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to Kivy. I am trying to open a dropdown when a button is clicked in my sample application. The dropdown is not visible when the button is clicked. Where am I wrong? Also, an explanation on the interaction between kv and python code will be very useful.

**main.py**

```
class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MenuBar(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MenuBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.newdropdown = NewDropDown()


class NewDropDown(DropDown):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = RootWidget()
        x1 = MenuBar()
        root.add_widget(x1)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
<MenuBar>:
    rows: 1
    row_default_height: 35
    row_force_default: True
    col_default_width: 100
    col_force_default: True


    Button:
        text: "MenuTitle1"
        font_size: 13
        on_release: root.newdropdown.open
    Button:
        text: "MenuTitle2"
        font_size: 13
    Button:
        text: "MenuTitle3"
        font_size: 13


<NewDropDown>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        row_default_height: 35
        row_force_default: True

        Button:
            text: "Product"
        Button:
            text: "Item"
```

Comment: Your dropdown is never added as a child widget to any other widget. Does it help if you call `self.add_widget(self.newdropdown)` where your DropDown get's created?

Comment: If I add, the dropdown is displayed by default. It disappears when I click on any widget.